# Why did the app name "Android OS" suddenly spike in data usage?

Tags: nexus-7, data-monitoring

I have a couple of questions here.  I am using the 2nd generation Nexus 7 tablet (wifi only) that was connected to my personal mobile hot spot.
Yesterday, I saw a spike in my data usage that was lumped under a process called "Android OS" that I had not seen before, in the few months that I have owned this device and started tracking its data usage.

In the course of 1 hour, it devoured about a gigabyte of (background) data according to the "data usage" under the settings.

I also have the Onavo app.  In that same time, it reports the data usage under the process "Streaming Media".

I presume "Streaming Media" and "Android OS" are the same underlying process.   Am I correct?  If so, why are they reported differently in these apps?

I have just discovered "Mobile Hot Spot" spot setting so I'm hoping that will help.  As I had not seen this process usage this much database before, I had not thought to look into tweaking this setting until I started Googling around.

Can someone fill me in a little more here, or why I might have seen this sudden spike in data usage which I hadn't seen before?  The only big streaming app I used yesterday was Spotify.

Comment: Your device must have been downloading OTA updates..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Are OTA-Updates *streaming media* (see question text)? Or is the reporting from Onavo supposedly wrong here? Though OTA was my first idea as well, until I noticed the "streaming" part.

Comment: No. Streaming Media is a different thing...